# Spectral Theorem for bounded selfadjoint operators

Tags: real-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, orthonormal, adjoint-operators

Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be compact, self-adjoint on $H$ separable. Then there is an orthonormal basis for $H$ made up of eigenfunction of $T$.

The proof is based on this two fact:
\begin{equation}
T\neq 0 \Rightarrow ||T||_{OP} \quad \mbox{or} \quad -||T||_{OP} \quad \mbox{is an eigenvalue}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
TS\subset S \quad and \quad TS^{\perp}\subset S^{\perp}
\end{equation}
I have no idea to prove the first one.

\begin{equation}
\left(
||T||_{OP}=\sup_{u\in H, u\neq 0}\frac{||Tu||_H}{||u||_H}=\sup_{u\in H, ||u||_H=0}||Tu||_H
\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: You will need the spectral radius $\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma (T)}|\lambda|=\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}||T^j||_{OP}^{\frac{1}{j}}$ and $||T^j||_{OP}\geq||T||_{OP}^j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the inner product on $H$ by $( \cdot, \cdot)$ and we write $||T||$ instead of $||T||_{OP}$.

Furthermore we use that $||T||= \sup_{||u||_H=1}|(Tu,u)|$

($T$ is self-adjoint !). We cann assume that $T \ne 0$.

Then there is a sequence $(u_n)$ in H and a real number $ \mu$ such that

$||u_n||=1, |\mu|=||T||$ and $(Tu_n,u_n) \to \mu$.

Then

$ 0 \le ||Tu_n-\mu u_n||^2=||Tu_n||^2-2 \mu (Tu_n,u_n)+\mu^2||u_n||^2 \le ||T||^2-2 \mu (Tu_n,u_n)+||T||^2$.

It follows that $(*)$ $Tu_n - \mu u_n \to 0$.

Since $T$ is compact, the sequence $(Tu_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence. Without loss of generality we can assume that $(Tu_n)$ is convergent. From $(*)$ we see that $(u_n)$ converges. Let $u$ the limit of this sequence, then $||u||_H=1$ and $Tu= \mu u$. Hence $ \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $ \mu= \pm ||T||$.